# Annotate some scatter plot observations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, annotate

I have made a dumbbell plot in matplotlib using the below "example dataframe" (`df`) and code.

The result looks pretty good but I am unable thus far to annotate the dumb-bell plots with their average values in `df["avg"]` column.

[image]

Can somebody guide me how to add the average values for each observation above their respective red dots? Thank you much!

Code follows below:

```py
#example data
data = {'Brand': ['HC','TC','FF','AA'],
'2019Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
'2020Price':[25000, 30000, 29000, 39000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["avg"] = (df['2019Price'] + df[ '2020Price'])/2
df = df.sort_values("2020Price", ascending = False)

#dumb bell plot
plt.hlines(y = df["Brand"], xmin = df["2019Price"], xmax = 
df["2020Price"], color = "grey", alpha = 0.4)
plt.scatter(y = df["Brand"], x = df["2019Price"], color = "blue", 
label = "2019")
plt.scatter(y = df["Brand"], x = df["2020Price"], color = "blue", 
label = "2020")
plt.scatter(y = df["Brand"], x = df["avg"], color = "red", label = 
"average")

plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Iterate through the values for `'Brand'`, and `'avg'` with [`.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), and add annotations with [`.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).
- [matplotlib Tutorials: Annotations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html)
- Tested with `pandas 1.3.1` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Brand': ['HC','TC','FF','AA'],
        '2019Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
        '2020Price':[25000, 30000, 29000, 39000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["avg"] = df[['2019Price', '2020Price']].mean(axis=1)

df = df.sort_values("2020Price", ascending = False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

ax.hlines(y=df["Brand"], xmin=df["2019Price"], xmax=df["2020Price"], color="grey", alpha=0.4)

ax.scatter(y=df["Brand"], x=df["2019Price"], color="blue", label="2019")
ax.scatter(y=df["Brand"], x=df["2020Price"], color="blue", label="2020")
ax.scatter(y=df["Brand"], x=df["avg"], color="red", label="average")

_ = ax.legend()

# add annotations for average
for i, (j, k) in df[['Brand', 'avg']].iterrows():
    ax.annotate(f'{k:0.0f}', xy=(k, j), xytext=(-15, 5), textcoords='offset points')
```

[image]

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to create the scatterplots. This uses `matplotlib` as the backend and removes the need to import `matplotlib` separately.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Brand': ['HC','TC','FF','AA'],
        '2019Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000],
        '2020Price':[25000, 30000, 29000, 39000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["avg"] = df[['2019Price', '2020Price']].mean(axis=1)

df = df.sort_values("2020Price", ascending = False)

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', y='Brand', x='2019Price', c='b', label='2019', figsize=(8, 6))
df.plot(kind='scatter', y='Brand', x='2020Price', c='b', label='2020', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='scatter', y='Brand', x='avg', c='r', label='average', ax=ax)

ax.hlines(y=df["Brand"], xmin=df["2019Price"], xmax=df["2020Price"], color="grey", alpha=0.4)

for i, (j, k) in df[['Brand', 'avg']].iterrows():
    ax.annotate(f'{k:0.0f}', xy=(k, j), xytext=(-15, 5), textcoords='offset points')
```

Comment: I am not familiar with iterrows(), but your solution makes sense and works beautifully. Thank you for your code (including converting figure to ax format) and the matplotlib link on annotations!

Comment: using pandas to plot is so much easier also. Your code is like poetry, Trenton. Thank you again :)

Comment: @sb2020 You're welcome, glad this works for you.